# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore

Tags: codenameone

After sending android build today, the app started crashing every so often, especially when you edit a text field. The following is the stacktrace when it crashes. Any pointers ?

```
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at android.graphics.Canvas.native_restore(Native Method)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at android.graphics.Canvas.restore(Canvas.java:554)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidGraphics.paintComponentBackground(AndroidGraphics.java:370)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidAsyncView$AsyncGraphics$11.execute(AndroidAsyncView.java:484)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidAsyncView$AsyncOp.executeWithClip(AndroidAsyncView.java:70)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidAsyncView.onDraw(AndroidAsyncView.java:109)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15635)
12-26 23:57:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14568)
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in the gradient rendering code.

I suggest you avoid using gradients. They are slower than just using images and more expensive in terms of memory. We made some optimizations to them but these optimizations might cause them to look different on the device compared to the simulator.